# How do you make a command which restarts your bot in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a bot in discord.js. How do I make a command that restarts the bot?

Comment: Not enough information, what do you mean by restart? Like restart your nodeJS instance on some server or have the bot reboot it's initialized/current data?

Comment: I want a command that can turn off the bot, then turn itself back on.

Comment: If you run your bot on an service like Heroku, it will autorestart if you simply end the process

Comment: My answer would be to use something like Heroku as said in a comment, but I believe there is a way to do it within your js code, using a batch file to start your bot and then calling that and then using client.destroy(); I'm not sure exactly what you should use but look into running a batch file from within your bot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can reset a bot by using the `client.destroy()` method, then calling `.login` after again. Try something like this:

```
// set message listener 
client.on('message', message => {
    switch(message.content.toUpperCase()) {
        case '?RESET':
            resetBot(message.channel);
            break;

        // ... other commands
    }
});

// Turn bot off (destroy), then turn it back on
function resetBot(channel) {
    // send channel a message that you're resetting bot [optional]
    channel.send('Resetting...')
    .then(msg => client.destroy())
    .then(() => client.login(<your bot token here>));
}
```

If you set a ready listener in your bot, you will see that the `ready` event fires twice. I set up a ready listener like this:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready!');
});
```

Comment: This would mess up with the periodic tasks you have been running on the bot. I think it can be done using some commands that work outside the bot, like `pm2 restart` or something similar.

Comment: This doesn't work on later updates, since `client.destroy()` kills the entire client, and returns. So, `client.login()` will never be called, and the client stays destroyed.