# How do I make the project to auto restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots, javascript-objects

I make bot discord Plays a radio 24/7 [link radio live](https://sc.creacast.com/topmusic_strasbourg)

The problem here is that the bot stops every once in a while
Is there a solution to restart the bot every hour? When I manually restart the bot it works fine.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const request = require('request');
const GUILDID = ''; 
const CHANNELID = '';
const url = 'https://sc.creacast.com/topmusic_strasbourg'; 
client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log('done');
  voiceStay(GUILDID, CHANNELID);
  function voiceStay(guildid, channelid) {
    if (!guildid) throw new Error('id sv error');
    if (!channelid) throw new Error('id room error');
    let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildid);
    const voiceChannel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelid);;
    if (!voiceChannel) {
      return
    }
    voiceChannel.join()
      .then(connection => {
        const dispatcher = connection.play(url);
      });
  }
});
client.login("");
```

**Note**: My hosting provider only allows me to use javascript files.

Comment: What do you mean "stops"? The bot crashes, or audio stops playing, or it gets disconnected, something else?

Comment: audio stops playing

Comment: are you looking for a [crone jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636051/cronjobs-in-node-js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try:

- Using a kind of process manager:

  ```js
  const { spawn } = require("child_process");

  function loop() {
    const bot = spawn("node", [ "file_of_bot.js" ], {
      stdio: "inherit",
    });
    bot.once("exit", (code) => {
      // prevents restarting the bot if the code had a fatal error
      if (code === 0) {
        loop();
      }
    });
  }
  loop();
  ```

  Then you can exit in your bot after an hour:

  ```js
  setTimeout(process.exit, 1000 * 60 * 60)
  ```
- Using [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2):

  ```bash
  npx pm2 start file_of_bot.js
  ```

  ```js
  setTimeout(process.exit, 1000 * 60 * 60)
  ```
- [Destroying your client and re-logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48606345/5844241)

  - You may need to wrap the creation of the bot to recreate it, as `Client.destroy()` seems to prevent `Client.login()` from being called in the future.
- Exiting and re-joining the voice channel